# Docker .NET Core image build works on one host but not on another one

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

We have a `.NET Core 3.1` web application running in Docker container. This is the Dockerfile that we use:

```dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-focal AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build

COPY . .

RUN dotnet build ./MovieTickets.Web/MovieTickets.Web.csproj -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish

RUN dotnet publish ./MovieTickets.Web/MovieTickets.Web.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MovieTickets.Web.dll"]
```

We tried building Docker image on two different hosts with the following command:

```
docker build -t myimage --pull --no-cache .
```

Docker image creation is successful on `host1` (Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, Docker client v20.10.9, Docker server v19.03.12), but it fails on `host2` (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, Docker client v20.10.10, Docker server v20.10.10). The error on `host2` is related to NuGet package `BuildBundlerMinifier v3.2.449`:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1025: An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild.
Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: ContextID 34 should have been in the ID-to-project file mapping but wasn't!
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.BuildProject(String projectFile, String[] targets, String toolsVersion, Dictionary`2 globalProperties, Dictionary`2 restoreProperties, ILogger[] loggers, LoggerVerbosity verbosity, DistributedLoggerRecord[] distributedLoggerRecords, Int32 cpuCount, Boolean enableNodeReuse, TextWriter preprocessWriter, TextWriter targetsWriter, Boolean detailedSummary, ISet`1 warningsAsErrors, ISet`1 warningsAsMessages, Boolean enableRestore, ProfilerLogger profilerLogger, Boolean enableProfiler, Boolean interactive, Boolean isolateProjects, Boolean graphBuild, Boolean lowPriority, String[] inputResultsCaches, String outputResultsCache)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String[] commandLine)
```

However, we don't understand why build process passes on one host and fails on another? Isn't one of the main purposes of Docker to unify build&run environment no matter where the image is built? What could be causing the difference in build result? What else should we compare between the hosts?

Comment: https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/457

Comment: I saw this issue before. As far as I understand, using the approach mentioned in the issue, you just ignore the error and continue with the build. I am not sure if this is really desired behaviour, it sounds like a very dirty workaround.

Comment: Oh it is, just wanted to link drop in case you didn't find it. Don't know the solution.

Comment: Are the hosts the same processor architecture?

Comment: They are both `x86_64 amd64`.